# How to get character count like Twitter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

edit: The best solution i could come up with is provided by @Kyle Petryszak

I modified to actually count `\n` since it seems Twitter counts those as well

```
    from emoji import UNICODE_EMOJI

    num_emoji = sum(tweets.count(emoji) for emoji in UNICODE_EMOJI) # accurately count and track emoji
    ignored_chars = UNICODE_EMOJI.copy() # thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/q/56214183/11456464

    num_other = sum(0 if char in ignored_chars else 1 for char in tweet)
    print(num_emoji, num_other, str((num_emoji * 2) + num_other + 2)) # not sure what exactly
```

---

OP below

---

I have a string (`tweet`) that put together like so:

```
def construct_tweet(pihole, sys):
    tweet = ': ' + pihole[0]
    tweet += '\n⁉: ' + pihole[1]
    tweet += '\n: ' + pihole[2]
    tweet += '\n⁉⏭: ' + pihole[3]
    tweet += '\n⁉: ' + pihole[4]
    tweet += '\n: ' + pihole[5]
    tweet += '\n: ' + pihole[6]
    tweet += '\n⌛: ' + pihole[7]
    tweet += '\n⚖️x̅: ' + sys[1]
    tweet += '\n: ' + sys[2]
    tweet += '\n: ' + sys[3]
    tweet += '\n: ' + sys[4]
    tweet += '\n: ' + sys[5]
    tweet += '\n️⏳: ' + sys[0]
    # print(tweet) # always print tweet to console so we can see the output locally
    return tweet
```

the generated version is consistently much the same as what is below +/- 1-3 characters:

```
: 811,593
⁉: 32,143
: 18,527|57.64%
⁉⏭: 8,805
⁉: 4,811
: 5
: 2
⌛: 2019-05-19 08:37
⚖️x̅: 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
: 460M/1G|37.5%
: ens4, tun0, tun1
: 8G/28G|28.57%
: Linux-5.0.0-1006-gcp-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-19.10-eoan
️⏳: 2019-05-19 03:40
```

all told there are only 244 characters:

28 emoji

```
⁉
⁉⏭⁉

⌛️x̅

️⏳
```

and 216 other characters (counting spaces, special characters, a-z, A-Z, 0-9):

```
: 811,593
: 30,488
: 17,292|56.72%
: 8,533
: 4,663
: 5
: 2
: 2019-05-19 08:37
: 2019-05-19 03:40
: 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
: 461M/1G|37.6%
: ens4, tun0, tun1
: 8G/28G|28.57%
: Linux-5.0.0-1006-gcp-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-19.10-eoan
```

how can I accurately count and keep up with emoji (as 1 variable) and all the other characters (as a different variable)?

The only character that shouldn't be counted is '\n'

Comment: All "normal" characters would have their Unicode codes (obtainable through `ord()`) below 256. Apply `ord` to your string and count how many codes are above and below.

Comment: How does `pihole` and `sys` look like? Also don't use a inbuilt python module as a variable name `sys`

Comment: [`pihole`](https://github.com/mwoolweaver/tweetStats/blob/master/lib/pihole_info.py) and [`sys`](https://github.com/mwoolweaver/tweetStats/blob/master/lib/sys_info.py) are just string that put together from other things *hopefully it's not too horrible*. those string when put together appear as such `811,59329,64416,396|55.31%8,5664,682422019-05-19 08:372019-05-19 03:400.0, 0.0, 0.0461M/1G|37.6%ens4, tun0, tun18G/28G|28.57%Linux-5.0.0-1006-gcp-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-19.10-eoan` (not counting empty spaces and `:` as they are added with the emoji automatically)

Comment: @DYZ Actually below 128. From there there will be code pages in 8 bit encodings and in UTF-8 the 8th bit is a continuation bit.

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you. Interestingly, changing 256 to 128 won't change the results (exactly for the reason that you mentioned).

Comment: @mwoolweaver if an answer helped solve your problem in the best way for your use case and you aren't planning on posting your own answer, don't forget to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to thank the contributor for their work, and close another question on SO!

Comment: What is the purpose of separately counting emoji? What, precisely, is an emoji for your purpose?

Comment: Ah, I see you sort of answered this question in a comment to an answer. It's really better to clarify questions by editing the question itself.

Comment: Also edited the original question with the answer as well and gave it a better title.

Comment: If your intent is to find the same count as twitter will compute, then you can't just count emoji. You need to deal with emoji modifiers and zwj sequences in the same way twitter does. Also, not all codepoints have the same weight, if you care about non-european writing systems and math characters.

Comment: While those are all valid points. They seem to be a little bit out of scope for what I was trying to accomplish. My situation is fairly controlled as I know the characters I use won't not be counted, the emoji that are used are predetermined and won't change randomly. I only provided the feed back to GitHub as a way to maybe help them fix the problem in a more proper fashion. If the question itself should be reworded I will change it to something more suitable. As of now the code I provided is the solution to my problem as best I can see.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. There is a (rather massive) regex in the various implementations in twitter-text, derived from an official regex in the Unicode reference material, which can be used to accurately match emojis (in the manner that twitter does) but it needs to be augmented with code to distinguish single-width and double-width characters. Unfortunately, python is not one of the twitter-text implementation languages, and apparently you don't require accuracy. So I'll leave it at that.

Comment: Relying on other modules isn't the greatest solution, sure. But the `emoji` import claims to keep a dictionary of all available emoji https://pypi.org/project/emoji/ so I'm not sure how inaccurate the code is.

Comment: Also worth noting is twitter counts ALL emoji as 2 characters. https://blog.emojipedia.org/twitter-now-counts-every-emoji-as-equal/ so this means if you can correctly identify each emoji you can get a character count similar (if not exactly) to what Twitter does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a snippet I wrote that should lead you in the right direction:

1. You take a tweet, and sum up all of the emojis in the string.
2. Next you create a filter `ignored_chars` that contains all the characters that you do not want to count as others.
3. Count up the remaining numbers left in the string.

```py
from emoji import UNICODE_EMOJI

tweet = "SOME TEXT \n\n\n\nGOES HERE"

num_emoji = sum(tweet.count(emoji) for emoji in UNICODE_EMOJI)
ignored_chars = UNICODE_EMOJI.copy()
ignored_chars['\n'] = 0
num_other = sum(0 if char in ignored_chars else 1 for char in tweet)
print(num_emoji, num_other)
```

**Output:**

```
3 19
```

**EDIT:** Set dictionary key instead of appending to the string.

Comment: `ignored_chars = UNICODE_EMOJI + '\n'` gives an error for me on python3.7 `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'str'`

Comment: @mwoolweaver Added a fix as I forgot to set the dictionary key.

Comment: @SmackAlpha I was able to get this running in Python 3.7 with `pip install emoji`. Since this seems to be an environment issue on your part, could we discuss this in "Python" chat?

Comment: after setting the dictionary key and importing `emoji` all was good!

Comment: [the reason](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/issues/615) this question was raised.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that doesn't require any external libraries, just in case.

```
def is_emoji(c): return ord(c) > 0x2100
def is_newline(c): return c == '\n'

num_emoji = sum((is_emoji(c) and not is_newline(c)) for c in tweet)
num_normal = sum(not (is_emoji(c) or is_newline(c) for c in tweet)
```

The choice of 0x2100 is pretty much arbitrary; it's unlikely any "normal" character in an English text will be higher than that, but all emoji will be. But if you know your "normal" text will be only ASCII you can replace that with the more obvious 127.

Comment: Draconis, that's a pretty solid answer but doesn't take into consideration the newlines. Also, the Unicode spec shows that "emoji" start at `231A` and aren't in a single contiguous range of characters, though I can't tell if this is important to OP. See the Unicode [data tables](https://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/1.0//emoji-data.txt) for emoji for ranges.

Comment: @andrewgu Good catch! Fixed the newline thing. But I'd thought e.g. ℹ️ (U+2139) could be an emoji too?

Comment: Draconis, technically yes though `©` (U+00A9) and `®` (U+00AE) and more are emoji by Unicode spec (linked in my last comment). Not exactly sure why I only started considering them at "watch", sorry.

Comment: where `c = tweet`? or do i need to iterate of the string and pass each character individually?

Comment: tried to run it as you put it but it complain about iterating over a bool value

Comment: @mwoolweaver The idea is that `tweet` is your string. So `for c in tweet` iterates over the characters in the string.

Comment: Wonder why I got the complaint about try to iterating a bool value?